# CAN-bus board w MCP2515

Tags: can-bus

Has anyone tried  this CAN board?  It uses the Microchip MCP2515, but I don't see any docs or sample apps.

[Qunqi MCP2515 Controller Bus Module TJA1050 Receiver SPI Protocol for Arduino SCM 51](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015DO0M4Q)

also here:

[D33 MCP2515 CAN Bus Module TJA1050 Receiver SPI Protocol](http://www.banggood.com/D33-MCP2515-CAN-Bus-Module-TJA1050-Receiver-SPI-Protocol-p-1015302.html)

I've also been a board called NiRen that appears to be identical to these.

Comment: There aren't a lot of awesome examples out there using CAN in general. Are you attempting to talk to a car or a different type of CAN? There's a library for Python called [py-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.org), but it only implements [J1939](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1939)-compliant CAN systems. The ["official documentation"](http://www.sae.org/standardsdev/groundvehicle/j1939a.htm) is dense and must be purchased.

Comment: Eventually i'd like to have RPi's as nodes on CAN networks in cars, trucks, buses, etc., but first, I want to set up my own little CAN network with a few RPi's and Arduinos.

Answer (score 1):

Steps you can try:
Connections:

- 5V--VCC
- GND--GND
- GPIO10--MOSI (SI)
- GPIO9---MISO (SO)
- GPIO25--INT
- GPIO11--SCK
- GPIO8--CS
- Enable SPI on Raspberry Pi
  edit "/boot/config.txt" to enable SPI and reboot
- Time for the connections
- Check whether all connections done right by using "ifconfig can"
- You will require some basic installs to start.
  sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool

and compile the CAN utils.

For any other reference, check:

http://lnxpps.de/rpie/

If you have a MCP2551 IC board, try this

http://chadgibbons.com/2016/01/08/can-bus-hacking-with-the-arduino-and-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Link only answers are discouraged, it would be a good idea to summarize the information from the link in your answer.

Comment: Please see the edited one. Hope it Helps!